# Using stripos and substr to find a section of a file

Tags: php, function, substr, stripos

I'm trying to locate the section between the header tags in a file. I know the file is working and the location is correct, but the rest of the function does not seem to be working correctly.

```
function get_build_header() {
    $file = ('header.php');

    $startsAt = stripos($file, '<header>') + strlen('<header>');
    $endsAt = stripos($file, '</header>');
    $result = substr($file, $startsAt, $endsAt - $startsAt);
    require $result;
}
```

I've been trying return, require, anything in desperation to get this to work, as well as file_get_contents but nothing seems to change. What is it that is stopping this from working, as neither $startsAt nor $endsAt seem to return anything?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$file = ('header.php');` is your problem. Try `file_get_contents` again... `$file = file_get_contents('header.php');`

Comment: If I do something like this:
`$file = file_get_contents(EFCDIR . EFCCON . '/builds/currentBuild/' . 'header.php'); return $file` I get nothing at all. But without the file_get_contents, the file is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file_get_contents()` and a regex: `preg_match('#<header>(.*)</header>#mis', $fileContents, $matches)` You will find the content of the header tag in $matches[1].